# CD Based Usage of debootstrap?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, chroot, debootstrap

I have installed 12.04 xubuntu alternative with whole disk encryption on a machine. I am attempting to set up a schroot usage of backbox 3.01 (an ubuntu 12.04 derivative from what I can tell) under that installation.

When I run debootstrap to install the backbox from the backbox install cd as in:

```
sudo debootstrap --verbose --arch=amd64 precise /srv/chroot/backbox file://mnt/backbox... (cd path)
```

I get:

```
I: Retrieving Release
E: Failed getting release file file://media.../dist/precise/Release
```

The path displayed in the error message I trace to a file that is "Release" and has the release manifest in it, so I am assuming it looks like the target file. I have tried moving the CD contents local and `chmod` the files to be `777` to make sure there was not some access issue, but still is having the same issue.

I have checked to make sure there is no path globbing, or other issue as well.

So a couple of questions.

1. How do I get `debootstrap` to work with a CD based installation?
2. If (1) is not viable, then does anyone know of a online repo I could point debootstap to for backbox (http://)?

Answer (score 4):

Write this off as failure to RTFM... The problem in question was a missing "/" in the file:///...

Would be nice if the error message was a bit more descriptive.